# R ts( ) function to specify that data has been collected over 10mins interval in a single day

Tags: r, time-series, stat

I have word frequencies observed in a data corpus in a single day, across 10minutes time interval.
The data looks something like this:

```
word 00:00:00 00:11:00 00:22:00 00:33:00 . . . .  23:17:00 23:28:00 23:39:00
Robert  10       20        22       32   . . . .   10        11        10
Harvey  12       35        12       12   . . . .   15        26        9
```

I want to generate a time series object for this data using R.
I know that the ts() function can be used to generate time series object where I can specify the start year and the time-interval being months or quarters. Example:

```
ts(data, frequency=12, start=c(1946,1))
```

But, I don't know how can I use ts() to specify that data has  been collected over 10minutes time intervals in a single day. Any clue?

Also, as you can see my data has time information in the header. Can that be used to generate time series object in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly, your main options are

1. Use `ts()`, but read the help page and figure out that you can use `frequency=` *or* `deltat=`.  As your data frequency is in fact regular, you could could try something like `deltat=24*60/11`.  [ And looking at your data, it seems to be 11 minutes rather than 10 as your question title suggests. ]  `ts()` is useful if you want to fit ARIMA-class models.
2. Use the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) package and its `zooreg` class and see the documentation in the package vignettes. I find [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) to be more easy to work with.

Comment: thanks ts( ) works as per your suggestion. I will try zoo later.